# Unity LoadImage from bytes[] lag

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

sorry for my bad English. I am developing an application and I have to load an image ("Texture2D") using an array of "bytes, I do it with the Texture.LoadImage () function, but this function gives me lag on my devices and freezes the screen for a few seconds Is there a way to avoid this?

Image
[image]

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: Xiaomi redmi 5 android :(?

Comment: The image appears to be a cell phone photo of a computer screen. It is rotated incorrectly, probably due to bad EXIF data. Can you [edit] the question and replace it with a screenshot taken from the computer so that it might be more legible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the texture using the WWW class, I think its asynchronous, not entirely sure though